# Cannot access Paypal Sandbox Accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

PayPal:

Cant access paypal sandbox - if trying to appraoch directly, you are being redirected to the paypal main site.

If trying to reach the sandbox via the paypal developer site, 
browsed to Dashboard>Sandbox>accounts,
(find the facilitator and buyer accounts - which apperently do require decent passwords to work) than press "Click Me" just to fail again by being redirected to a page indicating:

"We're sorry.
Relying party validation error: client_id or redirect_url provided in the request does not match any of the registered clients. Please check the request and try again."

Comment: Verified on my side, and I had another internal engineer verify as well. I've gone ahead and filed an internal ticket for the sandbox team to take a look into what's going on. Just to try to get you over the hurdle, what are you trying to do with the sandbox accounts?

Comment: Create a subscription button to test a new site IPN. 

Btw. In one of the many attempts I had made during the day I was able to login to the sandbox, but the problem described above is still there. The one which succeeded included running in a (clean) private window and approaching the sandbox site directly. Approaching the sandbox site directly does not work in other cases... I am being forwarded to the paypal regular site... –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found a way aroudn this.

Problem: For some reason if you are a PayPal user and also wish to use the sandbox (in my case I have a seperate private account and a business account, and the sandbox is used by the busienss account), any attempt to approach the sandbox results in being redirected to paypal main site (at least in my region).

Solution: Use a seperate cognito or private window for the sandbox - never login to you your own account while working with the sandbox, and if you do, restart the browser and get a new private window.